# Using Jenkins CI for Unit Testing

Tags: php, android, ios, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm researching Jenkins for my development team and am starting to realize that what I'm wanting in the end is more Unit Testing and less Integration.

I'm not very interested in integration or deployment with Jenkins at this point.  What I mostly want for now is to automate testing when code is committed and report to developers when there is a problem.

Is Jenkins still a good solutions for what I'm trying to accomplish?

If it is, do I need to write all of my unit tests first and then add them to Jenkins?  Will I need a Jenkins job for each Unit test, or can I combine many unit tests into one Jenkins job?

Eventually, I want to automate testing PHP, Java (for Android) and Objective-C (iOS).

Thanks!

db

Comment: You will probably need a Mac as a Jenkins slave when running iOS tests. How this can be set up is [explained here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/01/ups-and-downs-with-continuous-integration-for-ios-apps-jenkins-xcode-cobertura-and-testflight/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Jenkins is definitely a valid solution, it will allow you to run tests for Android and iOS. For Php I can't say but I guess yes.

Jenkins is basically a script runner that can be plugged to a scm and run scripts triggered by scm changes. So write your tests, run them on your machine and just find a way to get them ran automatically through Jenkins for each commit : that's the essence of CI.

For Android and iOS, running build jobs and executing tests is a bit tricky as you need your build to run an emulator (although you can still attach a device to your server if you are rich enough). And there are some plugins for that like the Jenkins Android emulator plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jenkins (and virtually any other CI tool worth the name) is definitely capable of running unit tests.

An aside on the terms: The "integration" is "continuous integration" does *not* mean "integration test" (though you can certainly run those, as well). It refers to "integrating changes", that is, checkins. In day now (thankfully!) long gone, that wasn't a given: developers could go weeks without checking in, or only checking into personal branches. Integrating code into the mainline could take weeks. The (then revolutionary) idea to fix this was: build every night, hence the term "nightly build". The natural extension was to build continuously, which required a server to poll the CM system for changes.

With that perspective, you can't run unit tests *without* the integration, since you typically must first build, then unit test. As mentioned above: Jenkins' has [strong support for unit testing](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unit+Test): it will be readily modeled as a single job at the top level.

See also more powerful (and expensive) animals in this family, like [Electric Commander](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electriccommander.php).